Find and replace while preserving case with sed
I want to search and replace strings but keep the case intact using sed
For example, if I want to replace all occurrences of foo with bar, it should work like this:
foo --> bar
FoO --> BaR
fOO --> bAR
FOO --> BAR


Does the replacement word always have the same length? And can the initial word be part of a larger word?

@Thefourthbird Its normal search and replace but it should preserve case. So it does not need to have the same length, and it can be part of a larger word

Any reason this is being downvoted? Seems like a straightforward question to me.

Not my downvote, but you demonstrate no research or attempt of your own.

please update the question with some samples where the two strings are of different length and case, replace AAAAAbbb with xxx or would it be XXX or would it be something else?  replace AbbbbbbbbA with XyX or Xyy or something else? replace aBB with gHHgHHgHH or gHHgggggg or something else? replace A3A3b3A with XXX or XXy or Xyy or something else?  at some point you'll likely need to provide a textual description of how to 'maintain capitalization' when the length of the strings differ

@Anm I didn't downvote but the site exists to help people with their code, not to get people to write code for you, so you can expect downvotes and the question to get closed when you don't provide code in your question for us to help you with.

@tripleee Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for next time.

@markp-fuso I guess I did make an oversight with the length parameter, so I suppose it should keep the original capitalization if the replacing word is larger than the original. one.

Neither tool has the facilities to do this straightforwardly. With POSIX sed it's hard to come up with anything better than just enumerating the replacements:
sed -e '
    s/foo/bar/g
    s/Foo/Bar/g
    s/fOo/bAr/g
    s/foO/baR/g
    :

Some modern sed versions have nonstandard Perl conveniences like \L for case conversion, but there still is no convenient way to test the case of an input character.
With Awk, at least you can generate this script from the inputs.
awk -v from="foo" -v to="bar" '
    BEGIN {
        if (length(from)!=length(to)) {
            print "length mismatch" >"/dev/stderr"
            exit(42)
        }
        n = length(from)
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            f[i] = tolower(substr(from, i, 1))
            g[i] = toupper(substr(from,i, 1))
            t[i] = tolower(substr(to, i, 1))
            u[i] = toupper(substr(to, i, 1))
        }
        for(i=0; i<2**n; ++i) {
            a = b = ""
            q = i
            k = 2**(n-1)
            for(j = 1; j<=n;  j++) {
                c = (q > 0) && (q - k >= 0)
                a = a (c ? f[j] : g[j])
                b = b (c ? t[j] : u[j])
                if (c) q -= k
                k = int(k/2)
            }
            s[a] = b
        }
    }
    { for(r in s) gsub(r, s[r]) } 1'

This generates a bitmap to direct the logic while generating the array of substitutions s; when the bit in the current position is 1, we select the lowercase version of the current character, otherwise uppercase. Regular Awk does not have bitwise operators, so we use regular arithmetic to figure out the value of the current bit. (GNU Awk has support for bitwise logic, but really, it wouldn't simplify this much.)
The array s contains all the generated substitution pairs (s["foo"] = "bar", s["foO"] = "baR", s["fOo"] = "bAr", etc etc) and so for (r in s) loops over them all and replaces any matches it finds.
The Awk solution will exit with an error if the strings are of different length.
Demo: https://ideone.com/liZ3nh
With Perl, I imagine this would be somewhat more straightforward; but you asked about a sed or Awk solution, so I didn't go there.
Both of these solutions will replace transitively, i.e. if your replacement string matches the input string, you could get multiple substitutions, depending on how exactly they overlap. (It's not hard to prevent this; the t command in sed says to skip the rest of the script for the current line if the previous substitution changed something; in Awk, you can do nextline when there was a match.)
If your input might contain regex metacharacters ($, ., [, *, etc), you will separately need to escape them.

You should mention that requires GNU awk (or maybe some others?) for the non-POSIX > "/dev/stderr" extension. With any awk that'd be | "cat>&2" instead. nextfile would also be a non-POSIX extension and so would ** instead of ^ in 2**(n-1).

s looks like it might be an array of characters or strings so YMMV with what for(r in s) gsub(r, s[r]) does if any of the characters involved is . or & or what happens if the value of s[r] is another char/string that's also itself an index of s[]. Also YMMV with what the output sed commands do if any strings involved contain regexp metachars, round brackets, /s, backreferences, etc. Maybe just add a caveat that this will only work for strings of alphanumeric chars?

FWIW while it usually LOOKS like it'd work for some specific sample input, I've never seen the approach of generating sed commands from awk actually work robustly and it's always more complicated and less efficient than just doing the job in awk. I understand the OP asked for a sed solution but IMO this approach is up there with calling eval from shell, maybe worse.

The Awk script performs the substitutions in Awk, too. The array s contains pairs like s["foo"] = "bar" , s["Foo"] = "Bar", s["FOO"] = "BAR", etc etc. Thanks for the note about regex metacharacters; I added a paragraph at the end about that.

I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me when you say "The Awk script performs the substitutions in Awk, too" sorry.

@EdMorton A reaction to your comment about generating sed from Awk; though perhaps it wasn't about this answer specifically?

I was just talking about any sed 's/regexp/string/ in general. If you're talking about the awk script I posted, it's doing literal character comparisons and replacements by their position in the string - that doesn't have any of the issues associated with replacing strings that match regexps with other strings that might contain backreferences as sed scripts do since every char in every string is treated literally.

I wouldn't normally answer a question that doesn't contain an attempt by the OP to solve the problem themselves, but multiple answers are already posted and it's simple to do in awk (which the OP will have on their system if they have sed) so...
Sed is great for simple s/regexp/string/ operations on individual lines but it wouldn't be a good choice for this as it doesn't have support for literal strings so you'd have to worry about escaping various metachars in various contexts (see Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed), nor does it have simple, portable looping constructs, upper/lower conversion functions, variables, etc. so even if you could come up with a sed solution for this it'd be more complicated and/or less portable and/or more fragile than an awk solution since awk doesn't have any of the mentioned issues.
Using any awk (and more variables than necessary for best clarity):
$ cat tst.awk
{
    oldStr = $0
    oldLgth = length(oldStr)
    newStr = ""
    for ( charPos=1; charPos<=oldLgth; charPos++ ) {
        oldChar = substr(oldStr,charPos,1)
        repChar = substr(repStr,charPos,1)
        newChar = ( oldChar == toupper(oldChar) ? toupper(repChar) : tolower(repChar) )
        newStr = newStr newChar
    }
    print oldStr " --> " newStr
}


$ awk -v repStr='bar' -f tst.awk file
foo --> bar
FoO --> BaR
fOO --> bAR
FOO --> BAR

If the input might be longer than your replacement string repStr and you just want the chars from repStr repeated if/when that happens then tweak it to be this:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { repLgth = length(repStr) }
{
    oldStr = $0
    oldLgth = length(oldStr)
    newStr = ""
    for ( charPos=1; charPos<=oldLgth; charPos++ ) {
        oldChar = substr(oldStr,charPos,1)
        repChar = substr(repStr,((charPos-1) % repLgth) + 1,1)
        newChar = ( oldChar == toupper(oldChar) ? toupper(repChar) : tolower(repChar) )
        newStr = newStr newChar
    }
    print oldStr " --> " newStr
}


$ echo 'FoodIsGood' | awk -v repStr='bar' -f tst.awk
FoodIsGood --> BarbArBarb

If you wanted anything else, whatever it is would also be trivial with awk but ask a new question about that so we can see your requirements, sample input/output and your attempt to solve that problem yourself.

This might work for you (GNU sed, grep and sort):
foo=foo; bar=bar
grep -io "$foo" file |
sort -u |
sed -E 's/.*/&\n&\n\n'"$bar"'/i;:a;ta
        s/\n[[:upper:]](.*\n.*)\n(.)/\n\1\\U\2\\E\n/;ta
        s/\n.(.*\n.*)\n(.)/\n\1\2\n/;ta
        s#(.*)\n\n(.*)\n#s/\\<\1\\>/\2/g#' |
sed -f - file

Identify all cased occurrences of foo in the file.
Sort and remove any duplicates.
Use sed to build a sed script to substitute every cased occurrence of foo with its equivalent cased bar.
Apply the generated above sed script to the original file.
The sed script builds a data structure consisting of copies of the original cased foo and a lowercase version of the replacement (in this case bar).
The sed script chips away at the original cased Foo turning uppercased letters in the replacement by \Ub\E where b is in F in Foo.
Lowercased letters are replace as is i.e a where o is in Foo.
The final output of the script are unique substitution commands for all cased foo strings.

This is a strange request, but it was a nice brain-teaser. My solution, however, will only work on strings of the same length - because otherwise, there is no information to define the case of the output.
#!/bin/bash
#input/output strings
input=$1 #tomfoolery
d=$2 #FOo;
e=$3 #bar;
# turn strings into character-arrays
D=($(echo "$d" |grep -o .))
E=($(echo "$e" |grep -o .))
# define output as empty
o=""
# permutate over the individual characters of 'd' and set the case of the corresponding character in 'e'
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#D[@]}-1)) );do
  printf '%s' "${D[i]} --> "; # for debugging only
  if [[ $(echo "${D[i]}" |grep -c '[A-Z]') -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "${E[i]}" |tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'; # for debugging only
    o=${o}$(echo "${E[i]}" |tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]');
  else
    echo "${E[i]}"; # for debugging only
    o=${o}"${E[i]}";
  fi;
done
echo "$o" # for debugging only
echo "$input" |sed "s@$d@$o@i"

Demo: https://ideone.com/uKk1r7
Call as bash thisScript.sh tomfoolery FoO bar or what ever combination is needed.

If I'm reading this correctly, it will just work on exactly the case variant in the input; i.e. it changes bar to bAr but will blindly replace FOO, foo, Foo etc with this static variant. (Also, the /i flag is nonstandard.)

@tripleee The '/i' flag is a GNU extension - sorry Apple. ;). The OP wanted to replace in his string substing A with substring B, while maintaining the case formatting of substring A. Populating the first three variables from the outside accomplishea that task. I modified the script to reflect that.

You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the dozen or so issues it'll tell you about. It'd also do various things given various input that contains non-alphanumeric characters, see my earlier comment and printf "$..." needs to be printf '%s' "$..." (try both if $... contains %) and echo $... could fail if - as the first char of $..., etc. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/133219). grep -o is also non-portable btw.

It's hard to write robust, efficient shell code to manipulate text (and even harder to do it portably) since that's not what shells are designed to do - they're designed to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The people who invented shell also invented awk for shells to call to manipulate text in general (and sed, grep, etc. for some specific simple text processing operations). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for one example of why some common, simple-looking text processing code in shell is hard to get right and best avoided.

Nice! I didn't know about spellcheck.net and I love it! Thanks.
grep -o  : found it here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html and didn't think anything bad about it.
In fact I chose grep -o . explicily for its effect of splitting the string d character-by-character into elements of the array D. Something other array creators explicitly prevent.
And as the arrays' elements are explicitly individual characters, I dropped the double-quotes around the array-calls.
I agree, that shell is not meant to be a text-editor, but IMHO my code is the least complex. ;)

FWIW grep -o is also not POSIX portable, though it is rather widely supported.

The place to check if anything is portable is the POSIX specs, e.g. for grep it's https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/grep.html. sed 's/./ & /g' or awk '{gsub(/./," & ")}1' would portably split a string into characters for populating a shell array. Regarding "as the arrays' elements are explicitly individual characters, I dropped the double-quotes around the array-calls." - individual characters doesn't mean you need to remove the quotes for the code to work and doing so makes your code more fragile, try E=( '*' ); echo ${E[0]} vs E=( '*' ); echo "${E[0]}"

When it comes to shell scripts least complex often means most fragile but I strongly disagree that your shell script is less complex than the awk script I posted and your script just swaps 2 strings so it'd need a surrounding loop added to be able to work on a multi-line input file (which would make it an order of magnitude slower again and may introduce more fragility) while my awk script already handles that and is far more robust, efficient, and portable.

A naïve Perl version:
replaceKeepCase :
#!/bin/sh
exec env perl -C63 -pe '
    BEGIN {
        $s = shift;
        @r = split //, shift;
    }
    s{(\Q$s\E)}{
        ($l,$i) = length $1;
        @m = map {uc eq $_} split //, $1;
        join "", map {$m[$i++] ? uc : $i<$l ? lc : $_} @r;
    }gie;
' "$@"

$ echo 'foö FoÖ fOÖ FOÖ' | ./replaceKeepCase 'fOö' 'BârQuuX'
bârQuuX BâRQuuX bÂRQuuX BÂRQuuX
$


assumes a UTF-8 locale (-C63 enables relevant switches)
first arg is search term, second is replacement
split replacement into individual characters
use s/// with /e option to treat RHS as code

quote search term to prevent metacharacter expansion

remove \Q, \E if they should be allowed


split each match into individual characters
create mapping table to decide how to change case of replacement at that position (1 = to upper; 0 = to lower)
apply mapping to replacement characters, retaining original case of any excess




if permutations are not too many, and permutations << matches, caching might give speed up. eg. ... s{...}{ $z{$1} //= sub{ original-RHS }->() }gie; ...
